# How to query a user Pointer<_user> field using Parse.com with Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Really struggling with this query, all I want to do is run a query through my Routines table selecting Routines that belong to a certain user. Running a normal query would require something query.whereEqualTo("routineIcon", "1") would bring up the the first and third row. However, the tricky bit is querying the user (Point<_user>) field, this is a reference to a user (objectId) from the User class. Initially I tried query.whereEqualTo("user", "RE1bvmzyPk"), but this came out blank so I looked into querying Pointers, I've trie d a few things but can't get it to work. Anyone got any tips?

```
private void retrieveRoutines() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Routine");
    query.whereEqualTo("user", "RE1bvmzyPk");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> routines, ParseException e) {
            if (e==null){
                mRoutines = routines;
                String[] routineNames = new String[mRoutines.size()];
                int i = 0;
                for (ParseObject routine : mRoutines) {
                    routineNames[i] = routine.getString("routineName");
                    Log.d("OK", routineNames[i]);
                    i++;
                }


            }

            else {
                //error
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The Routine Class is in the format:

**objectId (string) | routineIcon (string) | routinesName (string) | user (Pointer<_User>**

Answer (score 5):

You can create the user pointer by using the objectid of the user

```
ParseUser user=new ParseUser();
user.setObjectId("RE1bvmzyPk");

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Routine");
query.whereEqualTo("user", user);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> routines, ParseException e) {
        if (e==null){



        }

        else {
            //error
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want routines that point back to ( were created by a User )

Add the pointer field to Routines:

"createdBy"  type=pointer

And then query for it using the User Obj.

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Routine");
    query.whereEqualTo("createdBy", $userObj);
```